# How to get the mean of specific values from an nd.array region?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Given an ndarray:

```
np.array(
    (
        (1, 2, 3, 3, 2),
        (4, 5, 4, 3, 2),
        (1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
        (0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
        (0, 2, 3, 4, 0),
    )
)
```

extract the mean of the values bounded by a rectangle with coordinates: (1, 1), (3, 1), (1, 3), (3, 3).

The extracted region of the array would be:

```
5, 4, 3,
1, 1, 1,
0, 0, 0,
```

And the mean would be ~1.666666667

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(
    (
        (1, 2, 3, 3, 2),
        (4, 5, 4, 3, 2),
        (1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
        (0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
        (0, 2, 3, 4, 0),
    )
)
mean = arr[1:4, 1:4].mean()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, was the question too basic or not very well written? I am new here and by the down-vote pattern I got that I did  something wrong...

Comment: idk, you can try to read about [asking good qustions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in this link.   
Your post might be very basic to the point that a similar question must have been asked before. duplicated questions are not received well here as you can just look at other questions for your answer. If there is another post that answers your question it might be best to delete your question so that the site won't be filled with the same question over and over again.

Comment: Maybe one could say that I didn't do enough research effort, but I didn't find any good answer for the problem by googling around. Thanks for taking your time to help me anyways, cheers.